# How do I hide anchor text without hiding the anchor?

Tags: css

Say I have the following markup:

```
<li><a href="somehwere">Link text</a></li>
```

If I have a background image on the a tag, how would I hide the link text using just css? font-size:0 seems to work fine on the a tag apart from in ie7 little blobs show.

- Thanks for help so far I have used `line-height: 0;` and `font-size: 0;` and `text-indent: -999px`. But it still shows up some blobs in safari, any ideas?

Answer (score 209, accepted):

Try

```
 a{
    line-height: 0; 
    font-size: 0;
    color: transparent; 
 }
```

The `color: transparent;` covers an issue with Webkit browsers still displaying 1px of the text.

Comment: I have found this not to work in Chrome 15.0.874.120. Also have to add color:transparent;

Comment: @brokenindexfinger weird... but adding color:transparent works then? If so feel free to edit my answer and add that, or I can.

Comment: Adding `cursor: default;` can be useful too.

Comment: Seems great but it's hiding :before & :after too :/

Answer (score 19):

Wrap the text in a span and set `visibility:hidden;` Visibility hidden will hide the element but it will still take up the same space on the page (conversely display: none removes it from the page as well).

Comment: this is the proper solution, but I used display: none to also remove all sizing.

Answer (score 17):

```
a { text-indent:-9999px; }
```

Tends to work well from my exprience.

Comment: Ah nice didn't even think of that, I use that all the time for headers with images.

Comment: You may receive a performance hit by Google because you are telling the browser to draw a box at a width of 9999px, for each element that it is applied too.  Personally speaking, you are better off applying a display:none, visibility:hidden, font-size:0, or something to that effect to avoid the "possibility" of Google not respecting your over-extended layout scheme.  I use to code that way too, but I stopped.  source - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971152/is-text-indent-9999px-a-bad-technique-for-replacing-text-with-images-and-what

Comment: this also breaks `outline` on firefox. The outline rectangle will start from the left of browser viewport.

Answer (score 6):

Mini tip:

I had the following scenario:

```
<a href="/page/">My link text
:after
</a>
```

I hided the text with font-size: 0, so I could use a FontAwesome icon for it. This worked on Chrome 36, Firefox 31 and IE9+.

I wouldn't recommend color: transparent because the text stil exists and is selectable.
Using line-height: 0px didn't allow me to use :after. Maybe because my element was a inline-block.

**Visibility: hidden**: Didn't allow me to use :after.

**text-indent: -9999px;**:  Also moved the :after element

Answer (score 5):

```
text-indent :-9999px
```

Works flawlessly.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to hide based on bootstraps "sr-only" class.  If you wrap the text in a span with the class "sr-only" then the text will not be displayed, but screen readers will still have access to it.  So you would have:

```
<li><a href="somehwere"><span class="sr-only">Link text</span></a></li>
```

If you are not using bootstrap, still keep the above, but also add the below css to define the "sr-only" class:

```
.sr-only {position: absolute;  width: 1px;  height: 1px;  padding: 0;  margin: -1px;  overflow: hidden;  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);  border: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just need to add `font-size: 0;` to your element that contains text.
This works well.

Answer (score 2):

I have followed the best answer of Loktar and it worked very well. The only problem I had was with Chrome (my current version is 27.0.1453.94 m).
The problem I had was that it seems Chrome is aware that the text in the link is not visible and it puts the link a little bit lower then it is supposed to be (something like margin-top, but it is not possible to change it).
This happens with all the ways in which we make the text invisible:
- line-height: 0; 
- font-size: 0;
- text-indent:-9999px;

I was able to fix this problem by adjusting the vertical-align of the link like this:

```
vertical-align: 25px;
```

I hope this is helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can put an image into ::before pseudoelement and set the same  dimensions for  as is the image + add overflow:hidden, like:

```
li a::before{
  content:url('img');
  width:20px;
  height:10px
}

a {
  overflow:hidden;
  width:20px;
  height:10px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
<div class="hidden"><li><a href="somehwere">Link text</a></li></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I was able to fix this problem by setting  **font-size: 0** .

Answer (score -5):

How about `display: none;`

That hides anything.